# Consolidating multiple post_save signals with one receiver

Tags: django

So I read the Django source code (post 1.5) that you can now register multiple multiple signals to a receiver function:

```
def receiver(signal, **kwargs):
    """
    A decorator for connecting receivers to signals. Used by passing in the
    signal (or list of signals) and keyword arguments to connect::

        @receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
        def signal_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
            ...

        @receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=MyModel)
        def signals_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
            ...

    """
    ... implementation code...
```

However, I want to register multiple post_save signals from different **senders** to the same function. Right now, I just call

```
post_save.connect(fn_name, model_name)
```

for each model that I have. Is there a better way to do this with the new Django 1.5 @receiver decorator capability?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You can do that using the [`@receiver` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver):

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Model1)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model2)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model3)
def my_signal_handle(sender , **kwargs)
    # some code here
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, though it could be made more dry with a custom decorator.

Comment: It could be more DRY; however, I think that would be at the detriment of clarity in this case.

Comment: Best answer of the question

Comment: Agree with @freethebees. This makes it clear that there are multiple senders. A custom decorator would hide that fact (if only temporarily).

Comment: The required import is `from django.dispatch import receiver`.

Comment: Also: `from django.db.models.signals import post_save`

Answer (score 43):

Per the [Django documentation on receivers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions), **receivers by default do not need to be connected to a specific sender**. So what you're describing is default Django functionality.

In other words, to do this using the `@receiver` decorator you simply don't specify a sender in the decorator. For example:

```
@receiver(post_save) # instead of @receiver(post_save, sender=Rebel)
def set_winner(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    list_of_models = ('Rebel', 'Stormtrooper', 'Battleground')
    if sender.__name__ in list_of_models: # this is the dynamic part you want
        if created: # only run when object is first created
            ... set the winner ...
```

This assumes models that look like:

```
class Rebel(models.Model):
    ...

class Stormtrooper(models.Model):
    ...

class Battleground(models.Model):
    ...
```

Comment: won't this receiver also get called on *every* other model's post_save? that could be a lot of calls...

Comment: @nivcaner yes that's what the question was asking to do: use one `post_save` to listen for changes on multiple models

Comment: @TylerHayes multiple models is not the same as all models

Comment: @DylanYoung True. The answer is marked as accepted. If the question-asker feels this is no longer the best answer for their issue, they're welcome to change it.

Comment: If you made the list of models a set like `{'rebel', 'stormtrooper'}`, the `in` statement would be O(1) instead of O(N) and this is then no more complex than the multiple registrations in the now-accepted answer; with the added benefit that the `list_of_models` can be defined in settings or computed.
So a thumbs up to this one, thank you @Tyler Hayes!

Comment: this cause transaction error when you want to create and query or update modules even when u prevent the infit loop by if statment

Answer (score 22):

You can skip `model_name` and you will connect to all models post_save. Then you can filter if you are in right model in the handler:

```
post_save.connect(foo)

def foo(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender not in [FooModel, BarModel]:
        return
    ... actual code ...
```

or you can filter based on field in model:

```
def foo(sender, **kwargs):
    if not getattr(sender, 'process_by_foo', False):
        return
    ... actual code ...
```

Answer (score 15):

```
def receiver_with_multiple_senders(signal, senders, **kwargs):
    """
    Based on django.dispatch.dispatcher.receiver

    Allows multiple senders so we can avoid using a stack of
    regular receiver decorators with one sender each.
    """

    def decorator(receiver_func):
        for sender in senders:
            if isinstance(signal, (list, tuple)):
                for s in signal:
                    s.connect(receiver_func, sender=sender, **kwargs)
            else:
                signal.connect(receiver_func, sender=sender, **kwargs)

        return receiver_func

    return decorator
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Sorry but how is the usage? May you give a example?

Comment: I guess with something like this  `@receiver_with_multiple_senders(signal, [mymodel1, mymodel2])`